# jquery mobile/bootstrap bundle - attempted to call method 'bindRemove'

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use jquery mobile in my current project. Unfortunately I run into an error.

Jquery mobile loads up and everything is fine.
But whenever I click on any link on website, this error appears in console:
[image]

Then I have to refresh the page.

Here is my script order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

There are no other scripts at the moment. I have seen a few similar questions about attempting to call methods so I guess this order should be fine but who knows.

- jquery version: 3.6.0
- jquery migrate version: 3.3.2
- jquery mobile version: 1.4.5
- bootstrap budle version: 4.6.0

Why jquery migrate? Because whenever I omit it, I run into another error "Uncaught TypeError: a.event.props is undefined".
[image]

I have also validated HTML and it is valid.
I cannot provide any

Does anyone know, where might be a problem?

Comment: you probably have messed up html-markup, like unclosed div´s . Check your markup for example here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: It was really a markup. I checked markup only in Firefox and it seemed to be fine. Thanks to W3C validation I have not noticed, that pictures had spaces in names. That caused this error. Thank you, problem solved.